# how to fit MaterialCalendarView or apply scrollable in MaterialCalendarView

Tags: android, android-calendar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.15"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mcv_arrowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView"
            android:background="#1d925c"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headertext"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/emptyText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="No Record found"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my xml using this xml i am displaying top MaterialCalendarView and bottom some textview with Linear layout what happens MaterialCalendarView is not coming in top only  half date visible another half not visitable in smaller device so i want  fit it in top calendar-view with all date or    can we apply scroll on only MaterialCalendarView please suggest me how to achive  this .

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Scrollview** to show scrollable calenderview.

Show below code and change as per your requirement:-

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/gview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mcv_arrowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </Scrollview>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: apart from this any other solution so that we can fix in all device without scrolling @Janvi Vyas

Comment: apart from this you can manage parent layout height with **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**

Comment: i tried this but not set in smaller device  because  below part also i have to fit it

Comment: then you can use 1/3 format of your page means you can divide your component with **weight = 1** and **weight=3** and in parent layout specify weight sum means total of your weight. here, **weightsum = 4**

Comment: so, you can show both component which you want in smaller device also.

Comment: in this case bottom part will lesser

Comment: you can adjust bottom part as per your requirement means you can replace 1/3 to 3/1 or 2/2 part .So, your top and bottom part display with same height.

Comment: Is above suggestion is useful to you?

Comment: using scrollview?